# Is it possible for a flash drive to have 315MB capacity? How?

Tags: usb-flash-drive

I recently came across some flash drive that is 315MB in capacity. This makes me curious because normally flash storage usually came in as 256MB or 512MB. I suspect it could be a 256MB storage unit plus a 64MB storage unit, making it 320MB in total. Is this even possible?

[image]

I ran a quick diskutil command and realized it has no hidden partition.

Comment: I'm no expert but perhaps it has a partition of that size, and perhaps that partition could be deleted and made bigger, or resized.  But perhaps it could be the full capacity.  Also I notice that SSDs (which are essentially the same technology as flash drives), can have funny sizes   I googled for ssd hard drive capacities and I see a samsung at 480GB and a sandisk at 960GB   I don't know if that's true of MB too. I've no idea.

Comment: a program called rufus https://rufus.akeo.ie/  would be able to format it maybe it would delete that partition and create one and that might tell you the full capacity.. but it'd be more interesting to get more information about the usb stick while it's in this state. showing not just all partitions but also the full capacity. and even to be able to create multiple partitions.. Maybe linux's fdisk or windows's diskpart has a way to show you.. I haven't got a usb stick at hand to try.

Comment: The size that is being reported, is the size with a filesystem, the actual size is likely a great deal larger ( likely around 384MB ).  Of course it could also be 318 MB for obvious reasons.  *Flash storage can come in any capacity that is manufactured.*

Comment: The reasons manufactures use certain chip capacities, is because thats whats being sold, and it makes it easy on consumers to understand that 32GB is twice the size of 16GB.  *There are lots of consumers who literally know nothing about computers.*